# Minimizing a summation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How can I solve this exercise?
$min \quad {\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{c_i}{x_i}}} $

$s.t. \quad \sum_{i=1}^n{a_ix_i}=b $

$x_i \geq 0 $

$a_i,b_i,c_i >0$

My attempts.

I think I should calculate the derivatives: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial xi}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{x_i^2}$, but then I don't know how to go on and how to use KKT conditions with summatories

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my thought would be that you want all the $\frac {c_i}{x_i}$ equal.  To show that you should be able to do it for two terms and argue that if two terms are different the sum will be smaller if you make them equal.

Comment: @Valentina Sau I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your trying.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think I should calculate the derivatives: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{x_i^2}$, but then I don't know how to go on and how to use KKT conditions with summatories

Comment: By Cauchy's inequality $\left(\sum_i (c_i^{1/2}/x_i^{1/2})^2\right)\left(\sum_i(a_i^{1/2}x_i^{1/2})^2\right)\geq \left(\sum_i c_i^{1/2}a_i^{1/2}\right)^2$ and the equality is satisfied, when the vectors $\left(c_i^{1/2}/x_i^{1/2}\right)$ and $\left(a_i^{1/2}x_i^{1/2}\right)$ are proportional. Note that the left hand side of the inequality is $\left(\sum_i\frac{c_i}{x_i}\right)\left(\sum_i a_ix_i\right)=b\left(\sum_i \frac{c_i}{x_i}\right)$.

Comment: @logarithm Why do we got the equality when they are proportional?

Comment: That is part of the statement of [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality). If you look at [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Second_proof) you see that when equality happens, then $\|u-\lambda v\|=0$, which implies that $u-\lambda v=0$.

Comment: You can give an explicit solution. Let $r$ be the factor of proportionality. Then $r=(a_i/c_i)^{1/2}x_i$ for all $i$. Then put this in the equation $b=\sum_ia_ix_i=\sum_i a_ir(a_i/c_i)^{-1/2}$. From this you can solve for $r$ to get $r=b/(\sum_ia_i(a_i/c_i)^{-1/2})$. Having $r$, then you get each $x_i=r(a_i/c_i)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{x_i}=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{x_i}\geq\frac{1}{b}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{a_ic_i}\right)^2.$$
The equality occurs for $$\left(\sqrt{a_1x_1},\sqrt{a_2x_2},...,\sqrt{a_nx_n}\right)||\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{x_1}},\sqrt{\frac{c_2}{x_2}},...,\sqrt{\frac{c_n}{x_n}}\right),$$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Why do we got the equality when they are proportional?

Comment: @Valentina Sau Because it's the sense of Cauchy-Schwarz: $|\vec{a}\vec{b}|=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|$ for $\vec{a}||\vec{b}.$ There is a proof of C-S without vectors. I am ready to show, if you want.

Comment: No ok, I found it on the link posted here, so the minimum is the vector that annihilates the product, right? The fact I can't give a 'real' solution confuse me a bit, but I suppose there are no other conclusion

Comment: @Valentina Sau Yes, the product of two vectors-lengths is greater or equal to an inner product of these vectors.

Comment: Can I ask you something more? In a similar exercise I have: 

$min \quad {\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}}$

$s.t. \quad \prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}=1$,$x_i \geq 0$

Can I still use the same technique multiplying the summatory by the productory? Or it wouldn't have sense at all here?

Comment: @ValentinaSau For that you can use [the inequality between the arithmetic and the geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Second_proof). This tells you that $\sum_ix_i/n\geq (\prod_i x_i)^{1/n}=1$ and the equality happens only if all $x_i$ are equal.

Comment: @Valentina Sau I agree with  logarithm.  It's another technique. It's just AM-GM.